# Left floating divs not stacking correctly

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to stack 4 divs into a large rectangle. Its broken up into double wide and single wide divs with single wide being half the size of double. The first two divs floated flawlessly. However I want the next two to be reversed so when the user sees it they see double, single, single, double.

This is where the issue starts, the single is sticking to the right hand side for no apparent reason. If I put it after the double it works again but that's really against what I'm trying to do. I don't believe it to be a matter of spacing either, Ive made sure they have the space to fit next to one another or at least I believe I have.

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J84kp/1/)

```
<div id="hold-grid">
  <div class="doubleWide">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/677x349" alt="" />
    <div class="grid clear">
      <div class="doubleCell"></div>
      <div class="doubleCell"></div>
      <div class="doubleCell"></div>
      <div class="doubleCell"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="singleWide">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/339x349" alt="" />
    <div class="grid clear">
      <div class="singleCell"></div>
      <div class="singleCell"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="singleWide">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/339x349" alt="" />
    <div class="grid clear">
      <div class="singleCell"></div>
      <div class="singleCell"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="doubleWide">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/677x349" alt="" />
    <div class="grid clear">
      <div class="doubleCell"></div>
      <div class="doubleCell"></div>
      <div class="doubleCell"></div>
      <div class="doubleCell"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.clear:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
#hold-grid {
    width: 60%;
}
img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.doubleWide {
    width: 66.666%;
}
.singleWide {
    width: 33.333%;
}
.doubleWide, .singleWide {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.grid {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
}
.grid .singleCell, .grid .doubleCell {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
    float: left;
}
.grid .singleCell {
    padding-top: 51.4%;
    width: 100%;
}
.grid .doubleCell {
    padding-top: 25.7%;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: `float` are not meant for stacking, you need to use `position: absolute;` with `z-index`, p.s only going with the title and this line *I'm trying to stack 4 divs into a large rectangle.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `div` with a `clear` class after the second `#singleWide`

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ph8PB/1/)